# On blunders in PGNs

Tags: pgn, notation, terminology, blunder

Let us say that I commit a blunder in a chess game. One that is deserving for a ??, a mate in one let us say. My opponent misses it. With what mark should the move be written in a pgn? Left markless, or with a ?!. Or perhaps with something else?

Comment: If the blunder allows a mate in 1 instead of a mate in 4, it probably doesn't really deserve a "??".  A double question mark is usually reserved for a move that completely reverses the evaluation of the position (i.e. equal to lost or winning to equal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case you give, both the move that allowed the mate in one and the move that failed to take it are clear ??'s: they're both absoutely terrible moves.

Comment: I don't fully agree with you. I think that the opponent's move doesn't deserve ??. It is too harsh. What if he won a pawn or something similar?

Comment: "Forget it. Checkmate wins the game." - Nigel Short.

Answer (score 0):

A blunder is a blunder regardless of the opponent's response. Allowing mate in one in a playable position always deserves a ?? if you are adding annotations to a game.

Comment: What about my opponent's move. How should that be marked. That is my question.

Comment: I would agree with David Richerby, that the opponent deserves a ?? as well. Missing a mate in one is not excusable for either side.